# Get list of files with partial match on numbers range in bash 4

Tags: bash, glob

I've got a large number of files in the following format:

```
tile_4665_411_1000575_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100695_w30#ab.til
tile_4665_411_1000576_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100712_w30#aa.til
tile_4665_411_1001046_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100736_w25#aa.til
tile_4665_411_1001097_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#aa.til
tile_4665_411_1001120_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#ab.til
tile_4665_411_1001192_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#ac.til
tile_4665_411_1100653_w15#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#ad.til
tile_4666_411_1000468_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#ae.til
tile_4666_411_1000510_w10#aa.til  tile_6535_366_1100742_w25#af.til
```

and so on. These are the results from splitting large files into smaller files. Hence the naming convention (tile_**largeFile**_***smallFile***_uniqueidentifier_weight#split.til). Each individual ***smallFile*** is nested within **largeFile** (imagine splitting a square into subsquares each with the same size).

The next step is to ***cat*** all separate files belonging to largeFile_smallFile into one file as follows:

tile_**largeFile**_***smallFile***.tile

e.g. `cat tile_4665_411_*.til > tile_4665_411.tile`

We have room for 6700 potential ***smallFiles***, though about 30% of them are never created. At the moment, we're starting a job for each potential small_File and return out of the process if there is no such file.

```
numberofFiles=6700
listOfTiles==$(ls tile_*.til)
```

And then loop from 1 to 6700 nd grabbing the corresponding pattern:

```
PATTERN=$(ls tile_*_$COUNTER_*.til
#split filenames to get largeFile
cat $PATTERN > tile_largeFile_$COUNTER.tile
```

While this approach works, it is obviously not elegant and might lower our priority for execution (due to the number of processes we are requesting etc.).

Is there a smarter way to get a list of the individual small tiles that are actually in the folder?
I.e. something like:

```
numberofFiles=$(ls tile_*_{1..6700}_*.til) #unique smallFile numbers that are (potentially) between 1 and 6700
```

In a sense, I'd like to get the unique number of smallFile Id'S from a very large list of files.

Any help is super appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: This is too broad. [Edit] your question to include a [mcve] with emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: If you can write a regular expression to select the files you want, you could use `$(find / -regex 'YOURREGEX' -maxdepth 1)` to get the list of files matching the regex.

Comment: It's not really the number of files, it's the number of unique smallFile ID's and the actual unique smallFile ID's.